# Teamcity-Selenium tests docker error: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Cannot assign requested address

Tags: docker, selenium-webdriver, teamcity

I have a Selenium dotnetCore project that I execute against a docker image and now want to execute as part of teamcity.

I have teamcity build steps to stop and remove old docker selenium/standalone-chrome running images, steps to restore and build the test project, step to pull selenium/standalone-chrome:latest image.

Next, I have the below step which works fine for me when I run the tests from command line on my local system:
docker run -e TZ=Australia/Sydney --shm-size=2g -id -v "%teamcity.build.workingDir%\TestProjectAutoTests\bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1:/tmp" -p 4445:4445 selenium/standalone-chrome

However when I execute the same through teamcity step, I get the below error:

```
[00:01:55][TestProjectAutoTests: TestProjectAutoTests.Tests.RegressionTestsOne.TC_01] OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : An unknown exception was encountered sending an HTTP request to the remote WebDriver server for URL http://localhost:4445/wd/hub/session. The exception message was: Cannot assign requested address
  ----> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException : Cannot assign requested address
  ----> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException : Cannot assign requested address
TearDown : System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[00:01:55][TestProjectAutoTests: TestProjectAutoTests.Tests.RegressionTestsOne.TC_01]    at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.HttpCommandExecutor.Execute(Command commandToExecute)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.Execute(String driverCommandToExecute, Dictionary`2 parameters)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver.StartSession(ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor executor, ICapabilities capabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(ICommandExecutor commandExecutor, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities)
   at OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver..ctor(Uri remoteAddress, ICapabilities desiredCapabilities, TimeSpan commandTimeout)
```

I have tried with port 4444 too but I face the same issue.
Can someone please help me with the above issue. Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem but I think no body have any solutions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending the URI Remote address in RemoteWebDriver as below fixed the issue for me:

RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("selenium-chrome:4444/wd/hub"), chromeDockerTCOptions.ToCapabilities(), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(timeout)